# FATAL ERROR in JuliaCall: Symbol "ccalllib_libR.dylib74"not found

Tags: r, julia, fatal-error, julia-1.x

In `R` when running `julia_setup()` from `JuliaCall` package I get the following error:

```
Julia version 1.5.2 at location /Applications/Julia-1.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin will be used.
Loading setup script for JuliaCall...
FATAL ERROR: Symbol "ccalllib_libR.dylib75"not found
signal (6): Abort trap: 6
in expression starting at /Users/rod/Library/R/4.0/library/JuliaCall/julia/setup.jl:72
__pthread_kill at /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib (unknown line)
Allocations: 2283792 (Pool: 2283458; Big: 334); GC: 3
```

and `R` just closes.

#### Attempt 1

Reinstalling (in `Julia`) the `RCall` package had no effect. Neither reinstalling `JuliaCall` in `R`

#### Attempt 2

Specifying the directory and `rebuild = TRUE` increases the error message. However, it still aborts.

> JuliaCall::julia_setup(JULIA_HOME = "/usr/local/bin", rebuild = TRUE)

```
Julia version 1.5.2 at location /Applications/Julia-1.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin will be used.
Loading setup script for JuliaCall...
sh: line 1:  6137 Abort trap: 6           '/Applications/Julia-1.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia' '--startup-file=no' '/Users/rod/Library/R/4.0/library/JuliaCall/julia/rebuildRCall.jl' '/usr/local/Cellar/r/4.0.3/lib/R' 2>&1
FATAL ERROR: Symbol "ccalllib_libR.dylib75"not found
signal (6): Abort trap: 6
in expression starting at /Users/rod/Library/R/4.0/library/JuliaCall/julia/setup.jl:72
__pthread_kill at /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib (unknown line)
Allocations: 2283722 (Pool: 2283388; Big: 334); GC: 3
```

#### Edit 1

Calling `RCall` from Julia also throws a similar error.

> julia> using RCall

```
FATAL ERROR: Symbol "ccalllib_libR.dylib108"not found
signal (6): Abort trap: 6
in expression starting at REPL[1]:1
__pthread_kill at /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib (unknown line)
Allocations: 2319414 (Pool: 2319001; Big: 413); GC: 2
[1]    49111 abort      julia
```

Consistency in the comments found a similar error: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/rcall-vscode-repl-crash/46128

#### System information

> R.version

```
               _                           
platform       x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0   
arch           x86_64                      
os             darwin19.6.0                
system         x86_64, darwin19.6.0        
status                                     
major          4                           
minor          0.3                         
year           2020                        
month          10                          
day            10                          
svn rev        79318                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
nickname       Bunny-Wunnies Freak Out
```

and in Julia:

> julia> versioninfo()

```
Julia Version 1.5.2
Commit 539f3ce943 (2020-09-23 23:17 UTC)
Platform Info:
  OS: macOS (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)
  CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770HQ CPU @ 2.20GHz
  WORD_SIZE: 64
  LIBM: libopenlibm
  LLVM: libLLVM-9.0.1 (ORCJIT, haswell)
```

Comment: Hi. I cannot replicate the error on my mac with the same R version, Julia version, and OS version x86_64-apple-darwin17.0. So this may be a system issue? I later may update my system to try again. By the way, what is the result of `using RCall` in Jullia?  I also found this <https://discourse.julialang.org/t/rcall-vscode-repl-crash/46128> on Julia forum which seems related. But the question is still unanswered...

Comment: Thanks! I think you are on to something: RCall is not working either and throws a fatal error similar to the one you pointed out. I am editing my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some problems with `julia_setup` as well. This started after I updated R to 4.0.4 and Julia to 1.5.4. The problem turned out to be in Julia, where Julia was incorrectly trying to find some .DLL for R 4.0.3. I don't think I had R on my PATH variable before, but this helped.

Here is what worked for me:

1. Add R to your PATH.
2. Add Julia to your PATH.
3. (Reboot if necessary).
4. In Julia, run `add Rcall` and then `build RCall`. Before I added R to my PATH, `add RCall` would succeed but `build RCall` would fail.
5. In R, run `install.packages("JuliaCall")`, `library("JuliaCall")`, and finally `julia_setup(rebuild=TRUE, verbose=TRUE)`.